# How to render objects on the fly in opengl es 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

So I'm making an application where you can click on the screen and create an object on the fly. How should I go about doing this? I've created a seperate class that holds the properties of the object you want to create, a class for each specific shape I want to render, and an abstract class for the previous classes. But basically I just want to be able to click on a specific spot and it renders a specified shape centered on that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let your activity implement the OnTouchListener and overriding the folllowing method where you can retrieve the touch-coordinates:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    touchX = (int) event.getX();
    touchY = (int) event.getY();
  }

  return true;
}
```

On the touch event, you can then call your method to draw the desired shape passing the touchX and touchY values and do a translation.

Comment: Okay thanks, but I was mainly wondering like what kind of buffers or shaders i'll need to create in order to render the objects in the separate class. like what stuff can i recycle from my main activity and what do i need to create anew?

Comment: In your activity, just create an inner class implementing **GLSurfaceView.Renderer**. Manage all your shader handles, matrices, etc. there and just pass the shapes you want to render. You can hold the buffers (positionBuffer, colorBuffer, texCoordBuffer, normalBuffer) for a shape in the shape class themself.

Comment: If anyone wants to know the full answer I figured it out. you have to pass in the position and color handles, set the position, create a vertexAtrribPointer, do glEnableVertexAttribAarray, set the color position, do the same as above for the color with the attrib arrays. then draw the objects using glDrawArrays or elements. I also had to create a bytebuffer out of the vertices and put them at position 0.